# Trying to send smtp email in C#. No errors but does not get received. PHP works

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have a server that runs IIS and PHP. I have numerous webpages that send emails, some to me, some to the users. This all works great. I am on a Comcast Business Class account which means I can use smtp.comcast.net as my SMTP server, use port 25, and not use any sort of authentication which is great. And it works just fine.

Now fast forward to today. I am writing some custom C# code to monitor a folder structure and basically email me the new file if it matches certain parameters. In my C# code, I try to use the same settings, but it doesn't work. The SmtpClient.Send() function does not throw an Exception and my code completes the routine as if everything is happy and working. But then I wait and wait and wait, and I never receive the email.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.comcast.net"); 
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Timeout = 2500;
smtp.Send(mail);
onStatusUpdate("Successfully sent email to " + mail.To + (mail.CC.Count > 0 ? " and CC'd " + mail.CC.ToString() : ""));
```

The "mail" object is of type MailMessage and is setup with the To, From, subject, body, and CC. Also has HTML and Plain Text alternate views.

I guess the easiest question, is if there is a trick to sending email the oldschool port-25 way in C# that doesn't exist in PHP?

And the only reason I mention PHP is because I know my firewall isn't blocking port 25, I know my ISP has it open, I know I have the right server, I know it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this affects their Business Class accounts, but Comcast just recently (<2 months ago) closed off port 25 for all their email accounts. try using port 587

http://customer.comcast.com/help-and-support/internet/email-client-programs-with-xfinity-email/

Comment: They do not close any ports for Business class. And I get a few hundred status emails a day sent from the same server, on the same IP, with the same connection, using the same settings on port 25 but in PHP land.

Business class is totally worth the money. It is open, no bandwidth or capacity caps, no thorttling, and they even physically lock your wire into the switch box so that normal technicians cannot touch it when they are doing other installs. Almost 100% uptime, and the only downtime is scheduled with you personally a couple weeks in advance for a time that works! :)

Comment: cool, thanks for the info, sorry I can't help more, looks correct to me, I'd ask comcast level 2 support for help getting the mail logs

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look is in the mail server logs of the outgoing mail server that you are using to send this message.  These should tell you whether or not the mail server is even receiving the message from your C# program for queuing, and if so - what's happening when it attempts to deliver the message to the remote MTA.

Comment: I don't have access to those logs, it is being sent to the Comcast (my ISP) SMTP server. I don't think I can request log information for a specific email on a remote server with a remote callback... But who knows. I have never heard of it though.

Answer (score 0):

Well about 5 hours after I started testing, I got all my test emails at once including the embedded HTML and everything else. So it is working just as it should. I guess since the signature was slightly different they block them until they are deemed non-spam. It also appears that now when I send an email it goes through instantly.

So Comcast has some sort of time delay filter apparently for anybody else in the future with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding mails to the (to list),

and put sending in foreach for every mail I send mail separately,

and it worked!